# Maximal values of expressions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was working on the problem "Given $x+y+4z=15$, find the minimal value of $x^2+y^2+z^2$." I tried to solve the problem by using graphs, but I was unable to pinpoint the exact values. Does anyone know the appropriate way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hint

Let $k=a^2+b^2+c^2$

Eliminate one of $x,y,z$ say $x$ using $x+y+4z=15$ to form a quadratic equation in $y$ or in $z$

As $z$ is real, the discriminant must be $\ge0$

Answer (score 0):

Using Cauchy Schwarz we get
$$(x+y+4z)^2\le (1+1+16)(x^2+y^2+z^2)$$

Answer (score 0):

Viewed geometrically, we have the plane $x+y+4z=15$, and we inflate and deflate a sphere around the origin $O$ until it is tangent to this plane. Call the point of tangency $A$, then we want the squared length of $OA$.

By the form of the plane's equation, we see that $OA$ is parallel to $(1,1,4)$, so $A$ must be of the form $(t,t,4t)$. Since $A$ lies on the plane, we have $18t=15$ or $t=\frac56$ and $A=(5/6,5/6,10/3)$.

$A$'s coordinates are therefore the values of $x,y,z$ that minimise $x^2+y^2+z^2$, and the minimal value is $(5/6)^2+(5/6)^2+(10/3)^2=\frac{25}2$.